# Multiprocessing on a list of user-defined classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

so I have a data structure, Y, which consists of many parameters and a list, data, such that data is a list of data structures X. I'd like to do something like the following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
class X:
    def __init__(self, ** many arguments)

    def fix(self, smoothing, plot, tol, filter_fixed, impute, how_interpolate):
        do stuff with the arguments

    def filter_turnback(self):
        do stuff (no arguments needed)
        
class Y:
    def __init__(self, many_arguments, list_of_X)
        self.data = list_of_X
        self.*many_args = *many_arguments

    def fix_everything(self):  
        processes = []
        for i in self.data:
            args = [self.arg1, self.arg2...] #same args from Y passed to all X
            p = mp.Process(target=i.fix(), args=(args))
            processes.append(p)

        [x.start() for x in processes]
        if not self.condition:
             processes = []
             for i in self.data:
                 p = mp.Process(target=i.filter_turnback(), args=())
                 processes.append(p)

            [x.start() for x in processes]
```

But right now I can only do the fix_everything command sequentially:

```
class Y:
    def fix_everything(self)
        for i in self.data:
            i.fix(smoothing=self.smoothing, plot=self.plot, tol=self.tol,
                       filter_fixed=self.filter_fixed, impute=self.impute, how_interpolate = self.how_interpolate)
            if not self.condition:
                i.filter_turnback()
```

It's worth noting that the `fix` function in X is completely self-contained and doesn't rely on anything defined in Y except for X itself. The only ordering that is needed is that foreach X, `fix` precedes `filter_turnback`

I've already tried the following but am completely lost as it didn't work

```
import multiprocessing as mp
class X:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    def add(self, np):
        self.num+=np
        
class Y:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def multi_add(self):
        processes = []
        for i in self.data:
            p = mp.Process(target=i.add, args=([i.num])) #X.num = X.num + X.num
            processes.append(p)

        [x.start() for x in processes]
        
y = Y([X(i) for i in range(0,1000000)])
y.multi_add()
```

Comment: Your code has done absolutely nothing to ensure that "`fix` precedes `filter_turnback`".  In fact, you *never* call `filter_turnback()` on any `X` that has had `fix()` called on it, because each of your processes is working on a *copy* of the `X` that exists in the main process.  You would either need to return `X` from the `fix()` processes, and use that when launching the `filter_turnback()` processes, or call both methods sequentially in each process rather than having two sets of processes.

Comment: how are you going to wait till `X.fix()` has finished before calling `X.filter()`. Write a function that calls `fix()` first and then `filter()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a check for `__main__`, other wise you get an exception.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = Y([X(i) for i in range(0,10)])
    y.multi_add()
```

Much better to use a `Pool` because nobody has a 1000000 core CPU.

Comment: I appreciate the information, I guess I still need to research how to use pool then. Thanks.